# XSLT Transformation: move content of nodes into one node

Tags: xslt

I have following XML:

```
<EAD:c>
  <EAD:accessrestrict type="aaa">
    <EAD:p>
      value1
    </EAD:p>
  </EAD:accessrestrict>
  <EAD:accessrestrict type="bbb">
    <EAD:p>
      value2
    </EAD:p>
  </EAD:accessrestrict>
</EAD:c>
```

there are multiple `<EAD:c>` nodes, and not all of them necessarily have `<EAD:accessrestrict type="aaa">` or `<EAD:accessrestrict type="bbb">`

outcome after transformation should be:

```
<EAD:c>
  <EAD:accessrestrict>
    <EAD:p>
      value1; value2;
    </EAD:p>
  </EAD:accessrestrict>
</EAD:c>
```

i have no idea how to do this, your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:EAD="http://www.somens.com"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <outputDoc>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </outputDoc>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="EAD:c">
      <xsl:copy>
        <EAD:accessrestrict>
          <EAD:p>
            <xsl:for-each select="EAD:accessrestrict/EAD:p">
              <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
              <xsl:if test="position()!=last()"><xsl:text>; </xsl:text></xsl:if>
              <xsl:if test="position()=last()"><xsl:text>;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </EAD:p>
        </EAD:accessrestrict>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhDDz1

Comment: Thank you Sebastien. This is definitely a working answer to my question. Unfortunately, my "real" xml file is far more complex, so that your solution doesn't work. The thing is: Is it because of the larger xml or is it because there are also some more xsl transformations that are also in use? Hope i can find out.

Comment: Without seeing your input file and full transformation code I can't say. It most probably is not because your input file is bigger. If you can update your question with more detailed input we could help you out further.